# Edge/IE SVG CSS hover issue with viewBox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, microsoft-edge

I'm having trouble with SVG elements unexpectedly disappearing when applying a hover style in IE and Edge.  This appears to be caused by using a viewBox with a relatively large offset.

In Chrome and Firefox, the following code draws a red circle that turns yellow when hovered. However, in IE/Edge, the circle disappears and does not reappear when the mouse is moved away.

```css
circle {
  fill: #f00
}

circle:hover {
  fill: #ff0
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <svg width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="214700 0 100 100">

    <circle cx="214749" cy="50" r="10"></circle>  

  </svg>

</body>

</html>
```

I think it is related to the viewBox offset as changing the circle's x-coordinate to cx="214748" recovers the correct behavior.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Example: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/busahekeya/1/edit?html,output)

Tested in Edge 42.17134.1.0 and IE/11 11.165.17134.0 on Windows 10.

**Edit:** 
Issue reported to Microsoft https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/18322785/

Comment: The viewbox size seems **excessive**..do you really want something 200k+ wide?

Comment: I agree, the viewbox is not ideal but this is currently unavoidable.  I'm trying to understand why this is only a problem when hovering and then only in Edge/IE.

Comment: All browsers have bugs/rendering problems with large numbers.  I'm sure you'll find some Chrome/Firefox ones too if you insist on going down this road.

Comment: Also my understanding of viewbox is that it should be something like `0 0 larger x larger y` to define the bounds (at least as an ideal)...this is just plain weird - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/gjwaaM works fine in IE11 and requires little adjustment.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Are there any rules of thumb (or better yet specifications) for what a safe range of numbers is for parameters like these?

Comment: The [**spec**](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) indicates that the format of the viewbox should be a list of four numbers <min-x>, <min-y>, <width> and <height>, separated by whitespace and/or a comma so this looks badly formed. As such you're getting unintended results. Some browers can work around it...some can't.

Comment: The SVG spec recommends that renderers use double precision numbers. However, in practice, browsers tend to use floats.  That is mainly down to the underlying 2D graphics libraries that they have chosen to use.  Whilst it is bigger than usual, 214748 is nowhere near the limit of the float range.  So it is strange that it is causing problems.  You should definitely report it to Microsoft.